# Mysqli query doesn't work with id from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this php script.

```
$cwZ = count($wiegen_zutat);
$cwM = count($wiegen_menge);
$cwS = count($wiegen_schritt);

if($cwM == $cwS and $cwM == $cwZ and $cwZ == $cwS){
  for($x = 0; $x < $cwZ; $x++){
    $aktZuat = $wiegenZutat[$x];
    $qr = "SELECT ID_Zutat FROM Zutaten WHERE Name='$aktZutat' LIMIT 1";
    $id_get = mysqli_query($verbindung,$qr );
    $id = mysqli_fetch_array($id_get);
    $zuatenID = $id['ID_Zutat'];
    echo $id['ID_Zutat'];
    echo $zutatenID;
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Wiegen (ID_Zutat, Menge) VALUES ('$zutatenID', '$wiegenMenge[$x]')";
    $wiegenEintragen = mysqli_query($verbindung, $sql3); 
  }
}
```

$wiegen_zutat, _menge, _schritt are all three arrays which contain the information from my form. 
I go through the first array, and check the variable against a table which contains the ingredients for my website. I want to get the id of a ingredient which was added some steps before and add it into another table. 
The problem is that neither the echos or the query are working.

What am I missing?

Please don't get confused by the name of the variables, I'm german :)

Best regards

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attackes](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). Bind your parameters!

Comment: What does "neither the echos or the query are working" mean? What is the actual outcome? What is the expected outcome? Just knowing it doesn't work is not helpful.